# invalid identifier with Sysdate

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to query a table and get all records where the report date is the previous date.

```
select to_date(RPT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') Report_Date,
from tableY
where Report_Date = Sysdate -1
```

But I get an error saying invalid identifier in the where clause. RPT_DATE is a varchar in the table.
and is of the format yyyy-mm-dd.
How do I pull all records from the previous day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in the `where` clause.  In addition, you are missing that `sysdate` has a time component.

So, what you want is:

```
select to_date(RPT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as Report_Date,
from tableY
where trunc(to_date(RPT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = trunc(sysdate - 1) ;
```

Actually, this is not optimal because it prevents using an index on `RPT_DATE`.  In fact, storing `RPT_DATE` as a *string* is not optimal.  If it were stored as a date, you would use:

```
where RPT_DATE >= trunc(sysdate - interval '1' day) and
      RPT_DATE < trunc(sysdate)
```

Although this looks a bit more complicated, it can use an index on `RPT_DATE` -- assuming that column is stored as a date.

Comment: I got this error when I tried that. ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s". It looks like the RPT_DATE column is a number as suggested by its data type of varcahar. But sysdate is a date. Do I need to type case sysdate to a number? if so can I still do a -1 to go to the previous date? PS: The table is populated by a job. I am not sure I can change the data format.

Comment: This worked "where trunc(to_date(RPT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')) = trunc(sysdate - 1 );" But is that the right way to do it ?

Comment: @RLearner . . . Yes, given your data.  However, the column should be fixed to be a `date` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply `where rpt_date = to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`?